# Proving problem NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, proof-techniques, np

I am studying computational complexity and i am trying to solve this problem.
We are given a (non-bipartite) **complete** graph:

*G = (V, W, E)*

where the vertices can be divided in two classes V and W and the edges between any two vertices are weighted either 1 or 0.
*w(x, y) = {0, 1} ∀ x, y ∊ V ∪ W*

We need to:

- calculate a subset I ⊆ V ∪ W that maximizes the sum of the weights of the edges that link the elements of I, divided by the I cardinality.
  *max(1 / |I| ∑ w(x, y) ∀ x, y ∊ I)*
- The calculated subset I must have the same number of vertices of V and W.
  *|I ∩ V| = |I ∩ W|*

I would need to prove that this problem is NP-complete.

I have thought about reducing the problem to a vertex cover, removing the incident vertices to a 0 edge, but that would compromise the optimal solution.
And even considered this, i have found many difficulties trying to figure out a optimal certifier for the algorithm, which would prove the problem to be at least NP.
Any clues on a strategy to follow?

Comment: 1) You need to phrase the problem as a _decision_ problem. 2) " reducing the problem to a vertex cover" -- that's the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when doing complexity analysis, we usually think in terms of *decision* problems, i.e. the answer must be yes or no, and here you have an *optimisation* problem. This is why you are struggling to find a certificate here. If you reformulate your problem as a decision problem with an additional parameter $k$, and the question become "Is there a subset I such that the sum (...) Is greater than k ?", You will easily find the certificate : the list of the vertices in I, you can polynomially check that there are as many elements of V and W, and that the sum has the desired property.

Second, it seems like your are trying to reduce your problem *to* VERTEX-COVER. However, we already know that's possible because VC is NP-complete. To show that your problem is NP-Hard, you have to reduce a NP hard problem to it.

Finally, the reduction : maybe something from VERTEX-COVER will work : take an instance with a graph G=(V,E), make it complete by adding edges and put their weight to 0 (then your problem will not "try" to get them). If you find a clever way to divide V into V and W, the reduction might work.
However, it seems to me that VERTEX-COVER does not have a condition on sets and partitions, and you might have more luck with Subset-sum or 2-partition.

Edit : after a bit of thinking, If you make 2 copies of G (one becomes your V and the other W), and complete it with 0-weighted edges, you juste have to find the correct value for k... I think that's not too far.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for taking the time to answer! Note that we have compiled some [reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) that cover, in breadth and depth, some problems learners of CS frequently run into. You may want to check that list in order to avoid wasting time on writing the n+1-th answer re-hashing the same thing.